# Idiomatic way to return Err if an Option is Some

Tags: error-handling, rust, option-type

We can use [`or_else`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.or_else) and [`?`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.try.html) to return `Err` early if we encounter `None`:

```
let o = None;
let x = o.ok_or(666)?;
```

But what if we expect the opposite? Return early if something is `Some`:

```
let o = Some(42);
if o.is_some() {
    return Err(666);
}
```

Can we somehow do this with `?` as well?

Comment: afaik there is know way to do this other than with an if/match statement.

Answer (score 4):

I assume this is all about having it be a single line and saving characters.

You could use [`map_or()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.map_or), to convert `Some(_)` into `Err(666)` and `None` into `Ok(())`. However, this isn't idiomatic, I'd also personally stick to `if is_some() { return Err(666); }`, as what that is doing is more clear to the reader.

```rust
fn foo(o: Option<i32>) -> Result<(), i32> {
    o.map_or(Ok(()), |_| Err(666))?;

    Ok(())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo(None));
    println!("{:?}", foo(Some(42)));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Ok(())  
Err(666)
```

---

You could also create your own `ErrOnSome` trait. Naming the method e.g. `err_on_some()` it would be more clear and assumable to the reader what's going on, even without knowing the implementation of the `err_on_some()` method.

```rust
trait ErrOnSome {
    fn err_on_some<F, E>(&self, f: F) -> Result<(), E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<(), E>;
}

impl<T> ErrOnSome for Option<T> {
    fn err_on_some<F, E>(&self, f: F) -> Result<(), E>
    where
        F: FnOnce() -> Result<(), E>,
    {
        match self {
            None => Ok(()),
            Some(_) => f(),
        }
    }
}

fn foo(o: Option<i32>) -> Result<(), i32> {
    o.err_on_some(|| Err(666))?;

    Ok(())
}
```

*Using the same `main()` it produces the same output of course.*

---

**Edit:** Old answer - I misread and thought it was about returning `Option`

If the contained value is a primitive, i.e. cheap to *create*, then you could stick to [`xor()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.xor). However, this isn't idiomatic, I'd also personally stick to `if is_some() { return Err(666); }`, as what that is doing is more clear to the reader.

```rust
fn foo(o: Option<i32>) -> Option<()> {
    o.xor(Some(666))?;

    Some(())
}

fn main() {
    println!("{:?}", foo(None));
    println!("{:?}", foo(Some(42)));
}
```

Outputs:

```
Some(123)
None
```

Answer (score 2):

> Can we somehow [return `Err` on `Some`] with `?` as well?

I wouldn't call it *idiomatic*, but you can use `Option::map` to map the `Some` variant of the option into an `Err`. This will turn `Option<T>` into `Option<Result<X, E>>`, which you can transpose into a `Result<Option<X>, E>` and use `?` on that:

```
fn x() -> Result<(), i32> {
    let o = Some(42);
    o.map(|_| Err::<(), _>(666)).transpose()?;
    Ok(())
}
```

The turbofish on `Err` provides a necessary type hint because otherwise Rust can't determine the `X` of `Result<X, E>` mentioned above, and a result must have both an ok and an error type. I've chosen `()`, but it's completely unrelated to the `()` in the return type of the function; it could have been any other type because the `?` operator only cares about the error type of the `Result`.